# Translate command in oracle PL/Sql is not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting error when I run update statement with translate command.

```
UPDATE table_name
col1 = TRANSLATE (UPPER(col1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

> Error message is ORA-01407: cannot update col1 to NULL.
>   01407.00000 cannot update (%s) to NULL

Since there are 100k records in this column I cant find which row is throwing error. Is there any character which cannot be translated by TRANSLATE command?

Comment: Is there a NOT NULL constraint on the column or a foreign key?

Comment: You can't find the problem row(s) with: `select * from table_name where TRANSLATE (UPPER(col1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') is null` ?

Comment: I guess you have one or more rows which consist entirely of X, Y and/or Z ?

Comment: there is no null record in the column i am translating. Is there any character which cannot work in TRANSLATE command

Answer (score 0):

No idea what translate does, but shouldn't this work?

```
select *
from table_name
where TRANSLATE (UPPER(col1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ') is NULL
```

Comment: i can find the error record using the above query :(